# Email link to item created in another list by a workflow

Tags: email, list-item

We have an access request list and when someone submits a new item , it creates an item in a calendar.  If the date of the access needed is the same date as the date entered, I want the link to the calendar item to be emailed out.  I know how to link items with the **DispForm.aspx?ID=id** for items in the same list, but not with a different list.  I tried using **variable:create** after the **DispForm.aspx?ID=** but it opens an item that is missing all the information.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as how you do it for same list item. only thing is you need to know the newly created itemID then frame the URL pattern like below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding!  Unfortunately I tried that but it returns the item with blank information. And I can't seem to get a screenshot to attach here. But basically, it's not filling in the information of the title, location, etc.  Does not show created by and even though it's marked an all day event, it's giving it a time value.

Comment: If you mean values from the 'ListA' is not created in 'Calendar' columns then.. Did you map the fields correctly.. I mean in the above image I am creating the item in 'Values List' using 'Create item' action. When I click the 'Values List' I get a screen called 'Create New List Item' if you look at the right side there is a button called 'Add' click and map the fields from current item to destination item. in your case, it's from 'ListA' to 'Calendar'.

Comment: When the workflow creates the calendar entry, those fields populate just fine.  I'm having trouble linking to that specific calendar entry.  The recommendation you provided, does open up a calendar entry but it's not filled out with the correct info.  If I go directly to the calendar, it's there.  It's the link that I can't get to work.

Comment: Ok, get the 'display form name' when you manually open item from 'Calendar' list. then form the same URL in the workflow. now it should work.

Comment: If I follow, you're saying get the display form url, then after id=, put the variable that came from creating the item correct?  That's what I did and it's still pulling up the blank information.  Did I misunderstand what you are suggesting?

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, but do believe it has something to do with how SP calculates date and since we are using the "all day" function, it does not appear what I'm trying to do will work.  Thank you for trying to help though!